# Inverse of Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

I'm having problems understanding inverting permutations, but I believe I understand how to do compositions.  I may be second guessing myself, but some answers do not make sense to me.  I've tried to use two different approaches (graphically and P ∘ P^(-1) = identity)  Below is my question:

P = (5 1 4 2 3),  find the inverse of P

P ∘ P^(-1)=(5 1 4 2 3)∘(a b c d e)=(1 2 3 4 5)
P(P^(-1)(1))=P(a)=1⇔a=2
P(P^(-1)(2))=P(b)=2⇔b=4
P(P^(-1)(3))=P(c)=3⇔c=5
P(P^(-1)(4))=P(d)=4⇔d=3
P(P^(-1)(5))=P(e)=5⇔e=1
∴ P^(-1)=(2 4 5 3 1)

On a similar question I tried to find the inverse of (4 2 5 1 3), graphically using an arrow diagram and found that it's inverse is (4 2 5 1 3)!  Which doesn't make sense to me... unless that is suppose to be the correct answer...

Comment: Your two examples seem to be correct.  What is your question?

Comment: If these samples are correct then I'm good!  The text skimmed over the concepts (at least in my mind), and I wasn't sure I was getting the correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the cycle notation. Then the identity is not $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$, because that also denotes a cycle, rather the permutation with *empty* cycle decomposition, which might be denoted by $()$.

The cycle notation $(5\,1\,4\,2\,3)$ means the cyclic permutation that acts as following:
$$5\mapsto 1\mapsto 4\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 5$$
So, right in your first line, $P(a)=1$ would rather imply $a=5$. 
Anyway, its inverse acts simply backwards, i.e. as:
$$5\mapsto 3\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto 1\mapsto 5$$
which is the cycle $(5\,3\,2\,4\,1)\ $ [which equals to $(3\,2\,4\,1\,5)$, etc.]

Similarly, the inverse of $(4\,2\,5\,1\,3)$ is not itself, but $(3\,1\,5\,2\,4)$.

---

**Edit:** Having reread the exercise, it seems that the notation is *not the cycle decomposition*, but $[5,1,4,2,3]$ means the permutation $1\mapsto 5,\ 2\mapsto 1,\ 3\mapsto 4,\ 4\mapsto 2,\ 5\mapsto 3$. 
 
But, you can start out from any element and follow its orbit to find the cycle decomposition: $[5,1,4,2,3]=(1\,5\,3\,4\,2)$. 
In this setting, the identity is indeed $[1,2,3,4,5]$.

The other permutation you ask: $[4,2,5,1,3]$ will decompose as $(1\,4)(3\,5)$ as it does nothing but swaps $1$ with $4$ and $3$ with $5$. And indeed, it is its own inverse.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there are two notations for permutations. You probably used the direct one. Well.. you can find the cycle(s) as well to deduce to my solution : )

Comment: I think this is what's confusing me.  My text seems to be using the direct one, and I'm not sure if cycle notation has been covered, or will be covered either.   It seems like the inverses aren't simply the reverse order of the numbers, but twice now I've come up with an answer where the inverse is the same.  Both (3 4 1 2 5) and (4 2 5 1 3) end up with inverses equal to themselves.